# mysql query issue with multiple tables

Tags: mysql

So all of my other queries are working just fine. Except for this one that does not pull back any results.

```
$var = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, sku, quantity, style FROM catalina_warehouse, branford_warehouse WHERE sku='$data_search'");
$var->execute();
```

I don't see the problem here but if I remove the comma in between the two table names then it works and only pulls from the first table but if I leave the comma there then no results are pulled.

Comment: Is `sku` in both tables? If so, you need to prefix it with the tablename

Comment: add the table structures in the question.

Comment: If there's no data in `branford_warehouse` you'll get no data, if `sku` exists in both tables, you'll get an error (which you may be ignoring)

Comment: Both of my tables are nearly identical except for a few fields in there. That's why it's really confusing me. And it doesn't matter what table I have first in the query, it will pull data from only 1 table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indicate on the columns on the select line which table those columns are coming from.

On another note, i am assuming that the 2 warehouse tables have the same columns, but they just represent 2 different locations. This is generally not a good DB design practice. you could run into normalization problems which could cause data integrity problems and redundancy. you should have a products table with all their assorted info as well as a column that indicates which warehouse it is housed in and another table that lists the warehouses and all their info. make the warehouse column a foreign key references the warehouse table and you're golden. This can help with data integrity and with query design. But if my assumption is wrong, ignore this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Andrew, I'm going to go ahead and put that suggestion into practice.

Comment: not knowing how your database works, can your products be housed at more than one warehouse? If so, that calls for a different arrangement. If you could elaborate on how you database works (list out the tables and their columns), we can give you a better idea on how to better design it.

Comment: Well you are correct in what you were saying. It's all under one warehouse I was just separating the two types of products. I consolidated all items into 1 table and have 4 columns now which show the id, sku, quantity and style.

Comment: ok, i see what your saying. you look to be in good shape now.